# Universal Image Loader in most cases doesn't show image

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

I'm using universal image loader, to load images for custom info windows on my Google map. But in most cases it doesn't load images, it shows picture for empty uri.

Here's my code
In MainActivity:

```
initImageLoader();      
markers = new Hashtable<String, String>();
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showStubImage(R.drawable.loading)        
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty)   
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.error)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .build();

map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());              
ReadXML readXml = new ReadXML();
readXml.getXml(camera);

for (int i = 0; i<camera.size(); i++) {
    Camera cam = camera.get(i);
    LatLng coord = new LatLng(cam.lat, cam.lon);

    String title = Integer.toString(cam.id);
    String place = cam.place;
    String url = cam.img;
    Marker mark = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(coord)
        .title(title)
        .snippet(place)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.green)));              
    markers.put(mark.getId(), url);
}
```

Custom Info Window Adapter:

```
 private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter 
{        
    private View view;
    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() 
    {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                null);            
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) 
    {
        if (MyMapActivity.this.marker != null && MyMapActivity.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) 
        {
            MyMapActivity.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();                            
            MyMapActivity.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
        }            
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) 
    {
        MyMapActivity.this.marker = marker;
        String url = markers.get(marker.getId());             

        final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));


        imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) 
            {
                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                getInfoContents(marker);
            }
                    });

        final String title = "Камера №" + marker.getTitle();
        final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {
            titleUi.setText(title);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null) {
            snippetUi.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        } 
        return view;
    }               
}
```

And Universal Image Loader:

```
 private void initImageLoader() 
 {
    int memoryCacheSize;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR) {
        int memClass = ((ActivityManager) 
                getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getMemoryClass();
        memoryCacheSize = (memClass / 8) * 1024 * 1024;
    } else {
        memoryCacheSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
    }

    final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
            this).threadPoolSize(5)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .memoryCacheSize(memoryCacheSize)
            .memoryCache(new FIFOLimitedMemoryCache(memoryCacheSize-1000000))
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator())
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).writeDebugLogs() 
            .build();

    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at what the following line actually sets the sring to?

```
String url = markers.get(marker.getId());
```

I would suspect if this works like other google maps implementations that marker is a json string/object with multiple pieces of information and that you need to get it and then get the url from it. Try and do some logcat logging to be sure, you've posted a lot of code so it's hard to tell which parts are relevant.

Comment: I have `private Hashtable<String, String> markers;` where i put urls and marker ids. Sometimes it loads the link, and sometimes it is null, logcat says. But in arraylist all links ar correct

Comment: If you are using hashtable it cant hold any null keys or null values, have you logged everything as it goes through the loop adding to the table in case something is null and causing nothing to be stored?